# django editable dropdown list populated from queryset

Tags: jquery, django

I was looking for a possible way to make a django combobox populated from a queryset but I didn't manage to find sth relevant in the web. Is it possible to manage sth like the following?
I have a modelform and I want to render a field as combobox. 
Important: Not as the classic dropdown list using ModelChoiceField but as an editable dropdown list populated by queryset?
I know I can use jquery for that but then how can I populate it with a queryset?

Comment: What about https://github.com/theatlantic/django-chosen ( and http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ )?

Answer (score 0):

Django does support dynamic initial values, read more about it at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

You probably just need some kind of jquery plugin to make it editable. And indeed as suggested chosen would probably make a nice option.

Comment: 1)I can't see how chosen fulfills what I wanna do. I can't see a classic combobox but other 'select' widgets different from what I described. 2) my prob is not how I will populate it with dynamic initial values but with a queryset since an Autocomplete jquery widget gets populated with html-select-values. Correct me if I'm wrong.